# Why does my table value function work faster, when i modify it in SQL server management studio?

Tags: c#, sql

I crate a table value function and used it in my c# program.

- When i restart my computer, execute_time for calling this function (in c# program) is 5 minutes.
- But when i just modify this function (without any changes) and then run my program, execute_time is 6 seconds.

Who know that what happen when we modify a function?

What can i do to my execute_time always be 6 seconds?

Comment: You might find its nothing to do with editing the function. Start your app and call your function that takes 5 minutes. Then call the function again changing nothing and does it run in 6 seconds then?

Comment: This belongs on a DB site, the mechanics of this are more complicated then what it might seem, to prove its a cache thing, call `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` on sql sever and you'll probably find it takes ages again

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Excute_time does not reduce when i start my app for second time without modifying the function

Comment: I called DBCC FREEPROCCACHE after modyifing the function, but excute_time is still 6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

when you run the first time CPU takes time to figure out how to run a query.SQL Server uses memory to cache execution plans to save time the next time you run the query.
source of the information is [blog](https://littlekendra.com/2016/11/25/why-is-my-query-faster-the-second-time-it-runs-dear-sql-dba-episode-23/) read this blog you will get more info